# referencing method in the inner class from the outer class

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

i have the below code, and despite the classes and the memeber methods are public i  couldnt reference methodHF not methodBF inside the methodLMF. i tried the following:

```
LMF.this.xxxx //but the methods do not show up
```

please tell me how to fix it.

**code**:

```
class LMF {
    LMF() {}

    public methodLMF() { } // should return methodHF+methodBF

    //class HF
    class HF {
        HF() {}

        public methodHF(int x) {x++}
    }

    //class BF
    class BF {
        BF() {}

        public methodBF(int x) {x++}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the actual verifiable code. Not just the skeleton.

Comment: Those are instance methods, so you can only reference them if you have an *instance* of HF and an *instance* of BF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Objects of HF and BF in order to access there method.

```
class LMF {
    LMF() {
    }

    public int methodLMF(int x) {
        return new HF().methodHF(x) + new BF().methodBF(x);
    } // should return methodHF+methodBF

    // class HF
    class HF {
        HF() {
        }

        public int methodHF(int x) {
            return x++;
        }
    }

    // class BF
    class BF {
        BF() {
        }

        public int methodBF(int x) {
            return x++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new LMF().methodLMF(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it as

HF hF = this.new HF();
  hF.methodHF()